# Router: WRT54GL vs. Raspberry Pi

Tags: firewall, router

For routing and firewalling between 4 L2 networks, I currently use a WRT54GL (**without** using the WIFI). There are 4 networks routed which come in by VLAN from a managed switch, so a only a single Ethernet plug is needed. This solution works great: It is cheap, low-power, easy to add hot-standby devices (because it is cheap). The performance is not the best but it does its job.

Howver, there is not much memory: Tools such tcpdump would be nice to facilitate debugging or OpenVPN (which currently run a server behind). Also IPv6 is not very mature on OpenWRT.

Raspberry Pi would need similar power, is cheap as well but there is not memory drawback. It has only one ethernet plug, however, due to VLAN, this would not be a problem.

However, I am not sure if the Raspberry could provide a similar performance and stability (on the WRT, I have several hundred days of uptime!).

Anybone played around with the pi and can tell if this would work?

Comment: It sounds like you've got an idea about the hardware being able to function for you. Reliability testing or anecdotes really don't fit what our site is about, though. I'd say it's cheap... buy it, try it, and rollback if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Raspberry but I know I run DD-WRT on my WRT54Gs at home at it works like a champ.  I've got OpenVPN running on it and the performance is damn good considering my crappy Time Warner line at home it connects over.  Either way they have done a good job at keeping the footprint down in size and still providing a nice experience.  It is also fairly stable.  It has been up and running for about 230 days now with no hard re-boot.